# How to use "Knock [him/them] out of the water" — is this a common (if at all used) expression?

Tags: expressions

I can't seem to find much about this expression online, and its usage eludes me somewhat.

I'm guessing that it's supposed to mean that someone is being overcome by another party, a winner in a debate or some form of sparring?

Example sentence:

> They could swing their big money around and knock them out of the water.

Does that make sense?

Comment: "USAGE"!!! ahhhhhh :-)

Comment: @kalaracey I don't get it :?

Comment: Sorry, I just meant that lots of people get upset when someone uses the word "usage." It's a really *overused* word, but I'm sure its fine in your sentence. :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Usually the cliché used with *knock* is "knock them down."

Where water is concerned, the usual cliché is "blow them out of the water." The reference is to naval combat, which seems perfectly appropriate.

Comment: ahh duh :) too bad my email is already sent :P

Comment: +1 Mixed metaphor, probably confusion with *knock you out*.

Comment: ...and for additional oomph, say "blow them *clear* out of the water". :D

Comment: I think the original may be confused with 'knocked (it) out of the park'. A baseball allusion, I believe.